# best software to rapidly digitized family albums

Tags: photos, scanner

We have 100s of printed images in old family albums
I would like to go digital  with them.  I have  the most basic scanner (CanonScan lide 70)  with no feeder and a tight budget.

I was wondering there is some software that will allow me to scan 4 photos at a time and them automatically save them to separate files.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Any prefered operating system? If so indicate it in your question in the text and via a tag like `linux`, `osx`, `os2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the batches scanned, ImageJ can be pressed into doing the work of seperating the groups into individual images.  [This ArsTechnica Forum post](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=1327998#p1327998) has a link to both ImageJ and the script required to do the job.

That said, a photo scanning service like ScanCafe will give you much higher quality results.  Services like this will have better scanners and tools to make sure that your scans look as good as possible.  If you don't have the budget to have this kind of service scan all your photos, having them scan your favorites might be worthwhile while doing the rest yourself.